# Calculating $P(X \le 0)$ from the MGF of $X+Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, polynomials, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be identically distributed independent random variables such that the moment generating function of $X+Y$ is

$M(t) = 0.09 e^{−2t} + 0.24 e^{−t} + 0.34 + 0.24 e^t + 0.09 e^{2t}$.

Calculate $P(X \le 0)$.

**My attempt**

Let $u=e^t$

$M_{X+Y}(t)=\frac{1}{(10u)^2}(9+24u+34u^2+24u^3+9u^4)$

Now let $v=u+\frac{1}{u}$ and $p(u)=9u^4+24u^3+34u^2+24u+9$

$p(u)=u^2[9(u^2+\frac{1}{u^2})+24(u+\frac{1}{u})+34]=u^2[9(v^2-2)+24v+34]=u^2(9v^2-18+24v+34)=u^2(9v^2+24v+16)=u^2(3v+4)^2=u^2(3u+\frac{3}{u}+4)^2=[u(3u+\frac{3}{u}+4)]^2=(3u^2+4u+3)^2$

Thus $M_{X+Y}(t)=\frac{1}{(10u)^2}(3u^2+4u+3)^2=[\frac{(3u^2+4u+3)}{10u}]^2=(0.3u+0.4+0.3u^{-1})^2=(0.3e^t+0.4+0.3e^{-t})^2$

Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed, the MGF of $X+Y$ equals $(0.3e^t+0.4+0.3e^{-t})^2$, where $0.3e^t+0.4+0.3e^{-t}$ is the MGF common to $X$ and $Y$.

Thus $M_X(t)=0.3e^t+0.4+0.3e^{-t}$, and since $M_X(t)$ uniquely determines the distribution of $X$, it follows that $X$ is a discrete random variable whereby $X=-1, X=0$, and $X=1$ with respective probabilities $0.3,0.4$, and $0.3$.

$\therefore P(X \le 0)=0.3+0.4=0.7$.

When is it appropriate to use the change of variable technique (i.e. $v=u+\frac{1}{u}$) to factor polynomials and in what situations would it not work?

Comment: If you suspect that $M(t)$ factors as $(a e^{-t} + b + c e^t)^2$, then $a = \sqrt{0.09} = 0.3$ (from the coefficient of $e^{-2t}$) and $c = \sqrt{0.09} = 0.3$ (from the coefficient of $e^{2t}$), so $b = 1 - 2 \cdot 0.3 = 0.4$. Then you can check if the factorization really works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method works for *Quasi-palindromic quartic functions* as $$f(x)=a_0\cdot x^4+a_1\cdot x^3+a_2\cdot x^2+a_1\cdot  m\cdot  x+a_0 \cdot  m^2$$

In you case the parameters are $m=1, a_0=9, a_1=24$ and $a_2=34$. So you have a (real) palindromic function. For reference see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Quasi-palindromic_equation).

If you have not a palindromic quartic function, then you can multiply out $g(x)=(ax^2+bx+c)^2$ and then you compare the coefficients.